# Android: Way to set physical length of edit text field

Tags: android, user-interface, android-edittext

Is there a way to limit the input length of a Android edit text field using some sort of physical parameters (i.e. inches, pixels, etc.) I do not want to limit the field by character number.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Isn't it as simple as specifying the width - android:layout_width="40dp"?

Comment: that does not limit the input length though...only the physical size on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `android:maxWidth="100dp"` but that is going to set the max width of the View itself, and will not affect how many characters are allowed to be typed into it.

I do not beleive there is an easy way to accomplish what you want. The only thing I can think of is use a TextWatcher and dynamically determine how many characters will fit in the the size that you are wanting (which will be different for different devices). That is still basically "limiting  the field by character number" though which you state you don't want to do.

Can you elaborate on why you are wanting to do this? Perhaps there is a better way to solve the overall challenge that you are facing.

Comment: The input the user enters will later be transferred to a form that needs to be printed out. The amount of space for each field on the form is limited and since each text character takes up a different amount of space I was hoping to be able to limit the input edit text field by physical length.

Comment: IMO you are better off finding the width of the largest character ('M') and figuring out how many of those will fit, and then limit it to that many characters. The potential for extra characters based on smaller widths will be not worth the effort to implement it I think. @mtmurdock answer will get you on the correct path though if you do wish to move ahead with that.

Comment: if you could somehow get access to the Paint object that is drawing your text those might. I don't know how you'd be able to use that for an EditText though.

Answer (score 1):

You want to add a text changed listener ([TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)). In your listener you'll need to measure the size of the font, and the pixel density of the screen, and the number of characters. Multiply all of those together and you should know how physically long the text is (with a few caveats).

Having said that, this seems like a weird restriction and I'm not sure why you want this. Every device is going to have a different screen size, so measuring your interface in inches is typically a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could find how how many M's will fit in the printed form and then use [EditText.SetMaxEms](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setMaxEms%28int%29) To make sure the input will be printable on the form.

Answer (score -1):

Try this on your EditText

```
android:maxLength="10"
```

Comment: he stated in his question "I do not want to limit the field by character number." which is exactly what this will do.